# new to android - what is the benefit of having an xml document compiled into binary format

Tags: java, android

an online book I was reading states:

> To do this, you can place these XML files in the /res/xml/
>   subdirectory to have them compiled into binary format. But if you
>   place files, including XML files, in the /res/raw/ directory instead,
>   they don’t get compiled into binary format.

I am not sure what the purpose or benefit of having an xml file being compiled into binary format.

Answer (score 3):

A binary format will generally both give smaller file sizes and be faster and easier to process and scan. These are both very beneficial properties on mobile devices.

XML is designed to be read by humans and actually isn't super easy for computers to parse efficiently, although it is designed to be parsed reliably and consistently.

Comment: Actually, IMHO, JSON is way easier to read, both for humans and for machines. XML's syntax is too convoluted.

Comment: Personally I agree. I dislike XML and would much rather work in JSON. XML is a bit too entrenched to move easily though :(